# Disabling custom validations From Pages where it is used?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I am very new to ASP.NET. So apology for very basic question.

I have one custom control for Datepicker which is having 4 custom validator. I am using this datepicker in multiple pages by registering this control.

My idea is to disable some custom validation in some pages. That is in some pages I want only 3 of 4 custom validation and in some places I want no custom validation.

How can I achieve this. I don't want to create same custom control multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

Make that custom control as a helper class and reference it in different classes you wish to reuse.

For example I make this HelperClass:
     public class HelperClass
     { //do some shenanigans here }

On my other class files, add this line of code at the top.
     using project.model.HelperClass;

It's something like that. I don't really know what your code is but that's what I understood based on what you posted.